# Is the existence problem with Dirichlet/Neumann boundary conditions for ellipitic equations solved?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, potential-theory

Assume that $L$ is an elliptic operator of the form
$$L(u) = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \partial_i \partial_j u + \sum_i b_i \partial_i u$$
where $a_{i,j}, b_i$ are continuous functions on a bounded domain $\Omega\in \mathbb R^3$.

We assume $L$ is elliptic of uniform module $\lambda$, that is $(a_{ij})$ is symmetric for all $x$ and  $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j > \lambda \sum_i x_i^2$ for every $\xi\in \mathbb R^3$.
Assume furthermore that the boundary of $\Omega$ is a smooth orientable surface (with possibly several connected components $S_k$).

Under these conditions, is there a theorem that ensure the existence of $u\in C^2(\bar\Omega)$ such that
$L u = 0$ in $\Omega$, $u = C_k$ on $S_k$, with $C_k$ constant (Dirichlet conditions).

Same question if only $\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \partial_i\partial_j u $ is specified on  $S_k$ (Neuman conditions).

Same question if one or the other conditions above is specified on the $S_k$ (mixed conditions).

Please, provide references if possible.

Comment: you're looking for classical solution, i think chapter 6 of [Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order](https://www.amazon.com/Elliptic-Partial-Differential-Equations-Second/dp/3540411607) by Gilbarg and Trudinger is worth mentioning. specially subchapter 6.3.

Comment: If your coefficients are only continuous then the best you can hope for is $u$ is $ C^{1,1-\varepsilon}$